# What loggers to use and in which way should someone use it to so searching,analysing is easy

Tags: node.js, logs

I am trying to find good loggers using which I can search/analyse my server logs.
Should I use any readymade solutions like loggly or I start storing that in another server and use something like elasticsearch to analyse them.

I personally have a node js. My requirement is get the logs,search,analyse
and store them for 3 days at least